# How to make a unique claim in WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to make a unique claim in WSO2 IS management console. But cannot find any way to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current claim management implementation doesn't support having unique constraint for the claim values

But you can customize the user store to achieve this. You can refer to this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/) for more information about the customization.
You need to override the `setUserClaimValue` and `setUserClaimValues` and check for the existence of the claim value before setting them.

For example, the customization for the setUserClaimValue has to be like following

```
@Override
public void setUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String claimValue, String profileName)
        throws UserStoreException {

    if (// ClaimURI which needs to be unique) {
        String[] userList = getUserList(claimURI, claimValue, profileName);
        if (userList.length > 0) {
             throw new UserStoreException("Unique constraint violation for " + claimURI);
        }
    }
    super.setUserClaimValue(userName, claimURI, claimValue, profileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement should be having unique email to each user that logs in.If it is the requirement I suggest you to configure identity server email as user name.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/

Comment: yes i can do that by setting it as username but i want two unique things email and mobile............how do i make them both unique???

Comment: This can be achieved by configuring Authenticate using multiple attributes in WSO2 Identity Server. Please refer this blog post https://medium.com/@milindawickramasinghe/authenticate-using-multiple-attributes-in-wso2-identity-server-850915f06636